# Merging poker and poker-texas-holdem tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

This is by no means clear, but I'm wondering if the tags "poker" and "poker-texas-holdem" should be merged, especially since there aren't that many questions in either tag.

Answer (score 7):

No, [poker](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poker) accounts for all variants of poker while [poker-texas-holdem](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poker-texas-holdem) is just one kind of poker.

Comment: Yeah, and wouldn't Texas Hold'em be one of those variants of poker that are covered by the poker tag?

Comment: @Charles, yes, but having separate tags allows us to distinguish between a question that is generally applicable to poker and a question that is specific to a variant. Users can create a tagset for all Poker variants if they are tagged as such, but can't filter questions by title to get THE questions from a generic poker tag.

Comment: @Dave - agreed - I was just pointing out the flaw in Pat's answer.